# Force each row in Hive table to use a mapper

Tags: python, hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce, hive

Supposed I have a Hive table (named table), like so:

```
row1 2341
row2 828242
row3 205252
...
```

The table itself is very long (thousands of lines). I am doing something like this to run a transformation using a Python script:

```
FROM (
MAP table.row, table.num
USING 'python script.py' 
AS output
FROM table
) t1
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table2
SELECT (t1.output) as output_result;
```

The issue is that because I'm actually reading over a table and not files, each of the rows are being passed to the same mapper. This, as you can imagine, takes a long time. Is there a way to force each row to go to a separate mapper so that whatever logic is in the script can take care of everything else? Essentially, I want to run mapreduce like it's supposed to, but only passing in rows from a table to different mappers.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: data should not be going to only one mapper. If so, it does not depend on the script but how the data is stored in the table. For instance, if the data is stored as compressed text in one file, hadoop won't be able to split it to multiple mappers whatever you may do.

Comment: I need each line in the table to go to a separate mapper. Right now, the table is just a text file. Essentially, instead of passing in files to a mapper, I am passing in rows of a table (the table has multiple rows). Any way I can force this?

Comment: What I am saying is that it should be already going to multiple mappers. How big is the file ? Is it compressed  (.gz) ?

Comment: The file itself is a couple of kilobytes. So I'm passing in a string to the mappers and then the mapper will do things with that string like download data and make HTTP requests.

Comment: yep, like somebody else replied, it's too small for it to be passed to multiple mappers, it has to be bigger than `mapred.min.split.size` otherwise hadoop won't bother splitting it.

Comment: Is there a way to specific the number of mappers to use explicitly to go along with the number of lines in the table?

Comment: No, that would be kind against the design ideas behind hadoop. You can (actually, should) specify the number of reducers though.

Comment: To clarify, the system splits the load automatically based on the size of the input. The input is also stored already split in blocks - HDFS does that. This is done by design - data stored already split, ready to be processed in parallel - and specifying the number of mappers would go against this design, since to supply the number of the mapper you'd have to first split the input, which is less efficient than using input that's already pre-split for you.

Comment: One way you can do it is split the data yourself, that is, store your data in two gzipped files. Hadoop will not be able to neither split them nor combine them, and will use two mappers.

Answer (score 0):

Number of input splits are decided by Hadoop. But you may control it by setting 
`mapred.min.split.size` parameter.

Passing rows through table or through file does not matter as behind the scenes both are text files.

By default, a file in kilobytes would be passed to one mapper only. 
If you only want to try, you can create a file with size of around 1 GB and then run the query.

Comment: Is there a way to specific the number of mappers to use explicitly to go along with the number of lines in the table?

Comment: You can set the BLOCK SIZE(size of lines) and then a mapper will only take up those many lines.